# Ubuntu 18.04 netplan.io "unknown key" error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netplan

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and my netplan configuration in `/etc/netplan/10-my-config.yaml` looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "Raspberry":
          password: "your password here"
          mode: ap
```

(from: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109425/ubuntu-server-18-wifi-hotspot-setup/109427#109427?newreg=f5a4d31ada7549b1a6d5cc4dbb3fd294 - I would have commented there, but apparently you need 50 reputation to do this...)

I get the error: `Error in network definition: unknown key 'wlan0'`

I searched for it and all answers to this question say that the netplan version is too old. But mine is 0.101-0ubuntu3 20.04.2, so it's the newest version.

Can somebody help me resolve this error?

Comment: Welcome, see this answer on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/1222475/498780

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped!